# Review First post - Test reviews

Tags: bug, review, review-audits

When you make a First Post review, some time appears a review-audit to test if you're making attention in review tasks. However I note that some times this review-audits appears to be made by user who has more than 1 rep, I think that this is an error because if it's a first user post is not possible that this user has more than 1 rep and it's a clue to know that this is a review-audit post. I'm correct or I'm missing something? (I know that If you have a trusted user from another Q&A site you can have 101 rep but in this case your post not appears as first post isn't it?)

Thx! :).

Comment: It's called a "review audit" and it's on purpose to not make it too obvious it's a test.

Comment: @m0sa why did you remove the review tag? review audits are part of review.

Comment: Stuff takes about 15 minutes to appear on the queue, so by that time a person can have more than one rep on a genuine review. And with 101 rep from another site I believe that's still treated as a first post on the new site.

Comment: @ShadowWizard thanks for the comment, but I'm asking if is not suspicious that the review audit was made by user with more than 1 rep in First Post review. I'll check the other post that you said it's a duplicate of mine for see if there is more info.

Comment: @ShadowWizard because edit race? I just added the [tag:review-audits]

Comment: @PeterJ you're probably right, but the case you comment   probably not happens to much.

Comment: @m0sa oh, didn't think of the good old race. Not mad anymore. :-D

Comment: @albciff oops, you're right. But still, this is all by design and part of the review audit system.