# Old first post reviews on sites without audits enabled

Tags: support, review, new-users

This question was prompted by [Review First post - Test reviews](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235023/review-first-post-test-reviews) where often old first post reviews are possibly explained as being audit reviews. I believe audit reviews are only enabled on the larger sites as per [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work#comment520523_157121) on the question [What are review tests (audits) and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work)

On [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) and I think I've seen the same on [Pets](https://pets.stackexchange.com/) with audits disabled several times I've seen items in the first post review queue that are days to weeks old and they already have several upvotes and edits made in the interim. While not that old here is an example from today:

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/43829

While I can't tell the precise time it was asked an edit was made by JYelton at 2014-07-01 16:53:42 UTC and working back from the current time my review was around 2014-07-03 03:00 UTC so around 36 hours had elapsed. By the time I saw it the question had three upvotes and an upvoted answer. It didn't seem to require any additional action other than I did upvote it as an interesting question.

The first post queue on EE.SE is normally quickly processed so I'd find it extremely unlikely over that time a post would be ignored or skipped over continuously.  I wasn't really sure if this is a bug of some sort of a feature I'm not aware of that slips a few things back onto the first post review queue?

Comment: Maybe a user got the review and just navigated away instead of clicking "Skip", hence keeping it locked. After a while such locked items get back into the queue. Not sure for how long it's locked though, and if it's per-site or not.

Comment: I've got a rough idea that lock is 15 minutes or so, vaguely possible but seems unlikely for over 24 hours. But would interesting to know for sure.

Comment: Yeah, just a shot in the dark.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Questions are added to the queue when they qualify for it. Normally, a question qualifies as a "first post" *when it is posted* - but there are situations where this doesn't happen until later on:

- The author loses a large amount of reputation (for instance, by offering bounties)
- The post's score drops dramatically
- Other, earlier posts from the same author are deleted
- etc.

In this case, the author had one previous question, which was deleted a few hours ago thus making the one you reviewed the new *effective* first post from him.