# Why does community user 'editing' a 2012 answer show up in late answer review queue in 2015?

Tags: support, review, edits, late-answers

What's with this [late answer to an old question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/review/late-answers/116902) review?

[image]

I clicked 'No action needed' to verify that is was not an audit review (it wasn't).

My first reaction was to comment "Do not answer closed questions", but then I noticed the dates and the user that did the edit.

What is going on here?
Why would

- <strike>the community user 'edit' a 2011 answer 4 months later</strike>? Solved: *anonymous visitor suggesting an edit that was approved*
- that 2012 edit show up in the late answer review queue in 2015? I doubt it is still [initializing the late answer review queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/150080/why-does-the-late-answer-review-queue-sometimes-spike-in-size-by-over-5000) after 3 years.
- an *edit* show up in the late answer review queue anyway?

Note that the question is even closed (although probably not before 11 Mar 2012).

I searched here and read the [FAQ for Community user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user), but cannot find an answer.

Comment: Wonder if it's a more extreme example of this that I noticed a while back: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235024/old-first-post-reviews-on-sites-without-audits-enabled

Comment: Looks like a bug to me, the script that finds late answers shouldn't go that far back...

Comment: As for community user edit, it's just anonymous visitor suggesting an edit that was approved, no bug there.